# Flot rendering in IE 7-8 - chart label fonts are frong

Tags: canvas, internet-explorer-8, charts, internet-explorer-7, flot

I'm very confused why in my web-app Flot rendered label fonts very strangely, (see screenshot side labels besides the chart) while when viewing the Flot examples, they are rendered just fine in the same browser (ie 7 and 8 mode).

Any help would be appreciated.

-- fonts are supposed to be sans-serif.

[image]

Here are my page headers for example:

#### headers

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script>
            <title>Acme Inc. Contact Cloud</title>
            <meta name="description" content="View 's complete contact details on ContactMonkey.com." >
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex,noarchive,nofollow" />
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/system/favicons/45/original/favicon.png?1329843127" />
            <link href="/stylesheets/whitelabel.css?1335117438" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/autoSuggest.css?1335117438" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets-clients/acme.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/stylesheets/anythingslider.css?1335117438" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/colorbox.css?1335117438" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="/javascripts/flot/excanvas.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="/javascripts/flot/excanvas.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application_new.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/form_validations.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/css_browser_selector.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.form.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.remotipart.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.cookie.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.livequery.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.autogrow.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/si.files.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.anythingslider.fx.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.anythingslider.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.easing.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.keyfilter.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.cycle.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.autoSuggest.packed.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/edit_card_modal.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.resize.min.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

page specific scripts:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/charts.css?1335117438" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/javascripts/underscore.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/flot/jquery.flot.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/charts.js?1335117438" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the library that renders canvas text into IE 6-8 compatible text. There is no solution that I wound except rendering text as plain text, and switching to a different charting library.